# How to push files to git repository but not to Heroku?

Tags: git, heroku, bitbucket

Some files/folders I would not like to push to my production site on Heroku. But as I consider the git repository also as a back-up system, I do want to include these files when pushing to my git repository on bitbucket (using `git push`).

How should I make this distinction, given that `git push heroku` pushes everything to Heroku that was pushed to my bitbucket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you push a branch/commit to a remote, all files in that commit need to be pushed, because a commit is an atomic object. So I can see two options for what you want to do:

1. Create a separate repo that contains the files you don't want on Heroku
2. Create a branch that you only push to Bitbucket and add your files to that. Occasionally merge `master` (or whatever your main branch is called) into that branch if you want to have your private and public files mixed together on your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

```
git remote add [alias] [url]
```

visit your Github repository, it will show you the URL to use for pushing